# Rails Ajax request can't update page

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, jcrop

I'm using Imagemagick/MiniMagick to try to create an interface where the user can edit their images. I'm using the jquery plugin jcrop and then I'm trying to send the coords back to my controller to do the cropping then "refresh" the page with the cropped image. I don't want the whole page to refresh, I would like the cropped image to appear on the same page without going anywhere after they hit the button.

Right now i'm not even passing coordinates as I'm just trying to get the update portion to work with text but it doesn't seem to be doing anything.

```
$('#crop-image').click(function() {
    var x1 = $('#x1').val;
    var y1 = $('#y1').val;
    var w = $('#w').val;
    var h = $('#h').val;
    var assetid = $('#assetid').val;
    $.ajax({
      url: "/crop_image",
      data: assetid
    })
});
```

HTML:

```
Crop Your Own:<br>
<%= image_tag "#{@asset.file_name.url}", id: "jcrop-original" %><br>

  <%= hidden_field_tag(:x1, nil, id: 'x1') %>
  <%= hidden_field_tag(:y1, nil, id: 'y1') %>
  <%= hidden_field_tag(:x2, nil, id: 'x2') %>
  <%= hidden_field_tag(:y2, nil, id: 'y2') %>  
  <%= hidden_field_tag(:h, nil, id: 'h') %>
  <%= hidden_field_tag(:w, nil, id: 'w') %>
  <%= hidden_field_tag(:assetid, @asset.id) %>
<a href="#" id="crop-image" class="button radius">Crop Image</a><br>
<div class="panel" id="the-cropped">
Nothing has been cropped
</div>
```

route:

```
  get '/crop_image', to: 'products#crop_image'
```

controller:

```
  def crop_image
    @asset = Asset.find(params[:assetid])      
    #@mycropimage = MiniMagick::Image.open("public/#{@asset.file_name.url}")
    #@mycropimage.crop("#{params[:w]}x#{params[:h]}+#{params[:x1]}+#{params[:y1]}")
    #@mycropimage.write("public/uploads/asset/file_name/#{@asset.id}/mycropped_#{@asset.file_name.file.filename}")

    respond_to do |format|
      format.js
    end
  end
```

crop_image.js.erb

```
$('#the-cropped').html("Success");
```

My understanding was the Ajax goes to the controller the responds to the .js file which updates the HTML in "#the-cropped" but in my chrome console i'm getting:

```
GET http://localhost:3000/crop_image 404 (Not Found)
```

Any ideas?

Comment: What error do you get from Ror console?

Comment: Ah forgot to check that. Couldn't find asset without an ID. Commented that line out and it's working now.. thanks :)

Comment: haha. Happens. No problems. :)